# Django rename uploaded file: append specific string at the end

Tags: django, django-models, filefield

- I'm restricting the upload button to allow only csv files.
- I need help please to append **_hello** at the end of each file uploaded by the user, but before the extension. (e.g. **user_file_name.csv** becomes automatically **user_file_name_hello.csv**)
- Optional: I'd like the original file to be first renamed automatically, then saved to my uploads directory.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# validation method to check if file is csv
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
def validate_file_extension(value):
    if not value.name.endswith('.csv'):
        raise ValidationError(u'Only CSV files allowed.')

# Create your models here.

class user_file(models.Model):
    user_file_csv = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/user_files/', validators=[validate_file_extension])
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import user_file
from django.forms import FileInput

class user_file_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = user_file
        widgets = {'user_file_csv': FileInput(attrs={'accept': 'text/csv'})}
        fields = ('user_file_csv',)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
class FileUploadUtil:

    @staticmethod
    def my_files_path(instance, filename):
        name, file_extention = os.path.splitext(filename)
        name = 'prefix-{}-{}-sufix.{}'.format(name, instance.id, file_extention)
        return "my_files/{}".format(name)


class MyModel(models.Model):
    # Other fields
    # ...
    my_file = models.FileField(max_length=300, upload_to=FileUploadUtil.my_files_path)
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Optional: I'd like the original file to be first renamed automatically, then saved to my uploads directory.

You can override save() method.  Check here
[Django document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save)

Maybe You need decorator.

```py
from pathlib import Path


def rename_helper(path: str, append_text: str):
    stem, suffix = Path(path).stem, Path(path).suffix
    return f"{stem}{append_text}{suffix}"


def rename_previous_image(func):
    """ return wrapper object """
       
        
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        
        self = args[0]
        model = type(self)
        previous_obj = model.objects.filter(pk=self.pk)
        if previous_obj.exists():
            old_name_with_path = Path(str(previous_obj[0].user_file_csv))
            Path.rename(old_name_with_path , rename_helper(path=old_name_with_path , append_text="_hello"))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

And, You can decorate your model save() method.

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # Other fields
    # ...
    my_file = models.FileField(max_length=300, upload_to=FileUploadUtil.my_files_path)

    @rename_previous_image
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super(user_file, self).save(**kwargs)  # You must add This row.
```

besides,
recommend rename your user_file class

like UserFile

Check This [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Have a good day.